Hope for low worship buddhists
Can buddism help those who just worship a few statutes and have a small book and keep seeing the god in people online. Would god give a job and wife and maybe back to mainline plans or different.

I once met a group of Soka Gakkai practitioners, who met regularly to recite the Nam-myoho-renge-kyo mantra. They said it helped.

There are many different practices, but it would be fair to say they all start with having faith or trust in the Buddha, Dharma and Sangha. Because if you didn't believe it was worthwhile, you'd never bother learning about it, let alone putting into practice.
Recollection of the Buddha (Buddhanussati) is like worship, and was recommended by the Buddha himself according to the Pali Canon. The Anguttara Nikaya says monks who develop faith in the Buddha for even the time of a fingersnap do not eat the country's alms food in vain. And that's monks and nuns, who are held to a much higher standard than laypeople. The point is, every little thing has an effect, and nothing done well is wasted. Everything and everyone is changing all the time, which means they're changeable. Every time you mindfully choose to support a skillful thought instead of an unskillful, it makes a difference. Intention is karma, say the suttas. You can easily see what it does to you when you have nice peaceful thoughts and intentions instead of angry ones.
But acquiring material wealth is not what Buddhism is about. Making good karma and being generous (dana) may potentially result in some of your good actions coming back to you in this life, but the Teachings recommend practicing contentment with what you already have, and letting go of craving.

Monks, in this Teaching that is so well proclaimed by me and is plain, open, explicit and free of patchwork, those who have simply faith in me, simply love for me, are all destined for heaven. -Majjhima Nikaya 22
 
Take the case of another man. He is not even endowed with unwavering devotion to the Buddha, the Dhamma, the Sangha. He is not joyous and swift in wisdom and has not gained release. But he has just these things: the faculty of faith, of energy, of mindfulness, of concentration, of wisdom. Yet if he has merely faith, merely affection for the Tathaagata, that man, too, does not go to... states of woe. -Samyutta Nikaya 55.24

